# Using Task.Factory.StartNew with Action that takes single int parameter

Tags: c#

In the following code I pass an Action that is declared outside StartNew, looks fine.

```
Action ac = () => { Console.WriteLine("Executing Action in Task 7!");  };
var t7 = Task.Factory.StartNew(ac  );
Task.WaitAny(t7);
```

But I want to pass an  int parameter to action (I want to declare the action outside the StartNew).

```
Action<int> ac2 = (n) => 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Executing Action with 1 parameter = {0}", n);              
};
var t9 = Task.Factory.StartNew(  ac2  , 4); //Problem here????
```

Following code is fine as well but I don't want to use Action in this way. I want to define the Action outside and call it inside StartNew() like the above. How to use ac2 so I get the same result as below code.

```
var t8 = Task.Factory.StartNew(  (n) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing Action in Task 8!");
    Console.WriteLine("Param pass {0}", n);

}, 4 );
Task.WaitAny(t8);
```

Comment: Use `Action<object>` instead of `Action<int>`.

Comment: Off topic, but generally you should use `Task.Run()`

Comment: You can do this: `var t9 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ac2(4); });`

Comment: It's danagerous to use `StartNew` use `Task.Run` instead, http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why the existing answers are so complicated:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ac(4));
```

This is all it takes. Simply call the function wrapped in a lambda. Better use `Task.Run` as well:

```
Task.Run(() => ac(4));
```

`StartNew` is capable of taking another `object` argument but that's a very specialized API that is unnecessarily convoluted and should be used very rarely. It avoids the allocation of two small and short-lived objects. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional delegate function:

```
Func<Action<int>, int, Action> createDelegate = (action, arg) =>
{
    return () => action(arg);
};
Task.Factory.StartNew(createDelegate(ac2, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Action<object>` instead.

```
Action<object> ac2 = (n) => 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Executing Action with 1 parameter = {0}", n);              
};

var t9 = Task.Factory.StartNew(ac2, 4);
```

The StartNew() method has no overload to accept an `Action<T>` or `Action<int>` for this case. Only `Action<object>` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use overload that accepts `object` to send `Tuple<T1, T2>`  :

```
        Action<int> ac2 = (n) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing Action with 1 parameter = {0}", n);            
        };

        var _data = new Tuple<Action<int>, int>(ac2, 4);

        var t9 = Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) =>
            {
                var data = obj as Tuple<Action<int>, int>;
                data.Item1(data.Item2);
            }, _data);
```